# Production server: URL not opening

Tags: php, fopen

The URL is correct and parameters sent are confirmed to be working on the development server, but it keeps returning error on the production server.

```
$url  = "http://www.smslive247.com/http/index.aspx?";
$url .= "cmd=sendquickmsg";
$url .= "&owneremail=".urlencode($owenerEmail);
$url .= "&subacct=".urlencode($subAcct);
$url .= "&subacctpwd=".urlencode($subPwd);
$url .= "&message=".urlencode($msg);
$url .= "&sender=".urlencode($sender);
$url .= "&sendto=".urlencode($phone);
$url .= "&msgtype=0";

if($f = @fopen($url, "r")){
    echo "Successful.";
}else{
    echo $url." Error: URL could not be opened.";
}
```

When I try to return the URL and put it on the browser, it returns Success message.
What should I do?

Comment: You could start by *not suppressing the error reporting* from the fopen call!

Comment: How should I do that please? because the same code works well on my local machine (Development Server)

Comment: remove @ infront of fopen

Comment: Delete the `@` character

Comment: I just removed the @ character, and the error still comes up

Comment: And what does the error log say?

Comment: `fopen()` with URLs is often disabled on production machines in order to partially safeguard badly written PHP code against XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your host does not allow URL downloads.  This could be due to a few different things:

> 1. Your host has disable the use of fopen on URLs, which is most likely.
> 2. Your PHP version is too old to support wrappers.

You may resolve this issue by having your host allow or use `curl` to access.

Comment: I just implemented the curl function, and it works just fine, thanks a whole lot.

Comment: accept the answer if its useful :)

Comment: How can I stop the curl_exec() function from printing the returned messages from the url, I need to echo just what I want.

Comment: you can catch the response to a temp variable. $response = curl_exec($this->ch); and do whatever you want!